# jquery.load("external.php") Internal Server Error 500

Tags: php, jquery

Sorry if this was asked before it's only that I don't seem to get a working answer...
I'm trying to load an external php file using jquery but it gives an Internal Server error 500 which shows the error is on the server side.I appreciate any help..

my jquery

```
<script>
    function message() {
        $("#notifi").load("test.php");
    } 
    setInterval('message()', 1500);
</script>
```

The external php

```
  <?php
      include 'controller.php';
      $Nelsons = $King->query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE receiver='$boy' AND read2=''");
      $ccc = $Nelsons->num_rows;

      echo $ccc;



  ?>
```

Comment: add this after include line: `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`  and then check error

Comment: The error is on the server side. Do you have any access to server error logs? That's where you should be looking. (The jQuery is irrelevant.)

Comment: you're open to sql injection .. should probably try to fix this.

Comment: @Federico klez Culloca it gives this error Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: @E.Karimi is it hard to understand that server responds with 500 status without body? You should enable error displaying to see error reason

Comment: @num8er..I don have access to the server logs but this is the error the browser console gives

Answer (score 0):

For checking the PHP file has errors you could run the following command in command line:

```
php -l /path/to/filename.php
```

This will throw the errors in the PHP files in command line itself.